# Drawing LaTeX boxes

Tags: boxes

I want to write something like in the attached file.[image]

In particular I want the box to be flexible in such a way that it can contain the text -- both in the small box and the bigger one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An example with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
colback=white,
colbacktitle=white,
coltitle=black,
leftrule=0pt,
rightrule=0pt,
toprule=0.4pt,
bottomrule=0.4pt,
boxsep=0pt,
left=0pt,
right=0pt,
top=10pt,
bottom=10pt,
arc=0pt,
breakable,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
boxed title style={boxrule=0.4pt,arc=0pt},
title=#1}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{A title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's another option, allowing page breaks as the `tcolorbox` option, but using the also powerful [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{boxed}[1]
  {%
    \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,
      topline=true,
      bottomline=true,
      skipabove=\dimexpr\topsep+\ht\strutbox\relax,
      innertopmargin=\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+1.35ex\relax,
      innerleftmargin=0pt,
      innerrightmargin=0pt,
      singleextra={\path (P) -- node[overlay,draw,fill=white] {\strut#1\strut} (O|-P);},
      firstextra={\path (P) -- node[overlay,draw,fill=white] {\strut#1\strut} (O|-P);}
    ]
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{boxed}{The title}
\lipsum[4]
\end{boxed}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you used `\strut#1\strut` instead of `\strut#1`?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\parindent0pt\relax
\raisebox{6pt}{\hbox to \textwidth{%
  \hrulefill\fbox{\textit{DB}: \textbf{D}enominator \textbf{B}ounding}\hrulefill}}\par
$\bullet$ \textbf{Given} blah-blah-blah blah-blah-blah\par
$\bullet$ \textbf{Find} blah-blah-blah blah-blah-blah\par
\hrulefill}
\end{document}
```

[image]